# agregar una constante a un string ->php

Tags: php, html, html5

Quisiera saber si es posible agregar una constante **String**  a otro **String**.

Me explico; 
Tengo un ciclo que me llama `'X'` numero para una serie:

> 53148

Los tres primeros numeros son una serie de `fecha 06` y los dos ultimos de `fecha 03`

> fecha 06    :  531 
> fecha 03     : 48

Esta serie de numeros puede tener `'X'` cantidad de fechas mas .

Requiero que cuando la fecha cambie poder agregar un String `'0,'`Esto para poder hacer un cambio de categoria interno del programa el resultado final que espero seria:

> 5310,40,8

Separando las fechas:

> fecha 06    :  531 
> fecha 03     : 0,40,8

---

Codigo:

```
 foreach ($inventario as $x => $items ) {

     foreach ($items as $y => $descripcion) {
       echo $descripcion['stock'];


     }  
}
```

Estoy obteniendo los datos de una tabla de inventarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que debo concadenar el **String** cuando sale del segundo `foreach`; Pero no he podido saber como ir adicionando ese **String**, entendiendo que pueden cambiar varias veces la fecha.

```
//$Constante = '0,';
     foreach ($inventario as $x => $items ) {

         foreach ($items as $y => $descripcion) {
            //$str = echo $descripcion['stock'];   

         }    
         //$str +=$Constante 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador de concatenación es `.`. Tendrías que hacer

```
$str .= $constante
```

Pero en el bucle que muestras tienes dos errores:

1. `$str = echo $otra_cosa;` es erróneo. Si quieres pisar el valor de `$str` debieras poner `$str = $otra_cosa;`
2. Si pisas el valor de `$str` en cada iteración, al final del bucle principal sólo tendrás el último valor más la constante, por lo que quizás quieras poner `$str .= $otra_cosa;` e inicializar `$str` como un string vacío al principio del script.

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es:

```
$Constante = '0,';
$str = '';
foreach ($inventario as $x => $items ) {

   foreach ($items as $y => $descripcion) {
     $str .= $descripcion['stock'];   
   }    

   $str .= $Constante 
}
```

Sin embargo tu pregunta no explica exactamente qué quieres lograr. Si la tabla de tu base de datos tiene la estructura que muestras en la imagen, ésta daría origen a un array del tipo:

```
$inventario = [
    ['producto'=>'vodka absolut', 'fecha'=>'2018-06-01', 'stock'=>1],
    ['producto'=>'tequila olmeca', 'fecha'=>'2018-06-01', 'stock'=>4],
    ['producto'=>'whisky royal', 'fecha'=>'2018-06-01', 'stock'=>1],
    ['producto'=>'ron silver', 'fecha'=>'2018-06-01', 'stock'=>2],
    ['producto'=>'chimbombo', 'fecha'=>'2018-06-01', 'stock'=>2],
];
```

De manera que el bucle anidado no sería necesario, puesto que dentro del primer `foreach` ya podrías acceder al stock usando `$items['stock']`.

Si estás en cambio obteniendo un array anidado del tipo:

```
$inventario = [
    [
        ['producto' => 'vodka absolut', 'fecha' => '2018-06-01', 'stock' => 1],
        ['producto' => 'vodka absolut', 'fecha' => '2018-06-02', 'stock' => 3]
    ],
    [
        ['producto' => 'tequila olmeca', 'fecha' => '2018-06-01', 'stock' => 2],
        ['producto' => 'tequila olmeca', 'fecha' => '2018-06-02', 'stock' => 4]
    ],
    [
        ['producto' => 'whisky royal', 'fecha' => '2018-06-01', 'stock' => 2],
        ['producto' => 'whisky royal', 'fecha' => '2018-06-02', 'stock' => 1]
    ],
    [
        ['producto' => 'ron silver', 'fecha' => '2018-06-01', 'stock' => 5],
        ['producto' => 'ron silver', 'fecha' => '2018-06-02', 'stock' => 2]
    ],
    [
        ['producto' => 'chimbombo', 'fecha' => '2018-06-01', 'stock' => 2],
        ['producto' => 'chimbombo', 'fecha' => '2018-06-02', 'stock' => 6]
    ],
];
```

Entonces sí tiene sentido el bucle anidado.

Si hacemos el supuesto que quieres generar una cadena con la concatenación de cada stock más la constante, entonces al hacer:

```
$constante = '0,';
$str='';
foreach ($inventario as $x => $items) {

    foreach ($items as $y => $descripcion) {
        $str.=$descripcion['stock'];        
    }
    $str .= $constante;
}
```

El valor final de `$str` sería: `130,240,210,520,260,`

Pero tú dices que el valor esperado sería del tipo `numero,numero,numero` así que añadir la constante siempre hará que `$str` termine en `0,`. Imagino entonces que podrías hacer:

```
$constante = '0,';
$str=[];
foreach ($inventario as $x => $items) {

    foreach ($items as $y => $descripcion) {
        $str[]=$descripcion['stock'];       
    }

}
$str = implode($constante, $str);
```

En cuyo caso $str tendría el valor `10,30,20,40,20,10,50,20,20,6`.

Ahora, sigo sin imaginarme la utilidad de este bucle. Creo que **si lo que quieres en realidad** es añadir una columna `codigo` a cada fila de la tabla final, vas a tener que mostrarnos el contenido de `$inventario` y el valor esperado de tu tabla final.